# React native, dynamically position text

Tags: javascript, react-native, dynamic

I am trying to get the text to change position on the screen dynamically when I click a button.

I have my Text view like so:

```
<Text style={position: 'absolute', top: positionY, left: positionX,}></Text>
```

I have declared those variables at the top:

```
var positionX = 20,
var positionY = 20
```

When I press a button I run a function and change those values. I have used `console.log` to see if the values are changing and they are, however, the `<Text>` element does not change position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate anything within your app you need to do do with `Animated` Builtin Library .

make an `Animated.Value` then change it , whenever you change it if you have an 
Animated.Text with the styles of Animated value, they will be changed.
go through Docs for more info https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

If you dont want to use `Animated` you can easily use the `LayoutAnimation` before changing your state and it will handle it automatically https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation

Comment: I am not animating it. I do not want it to physically move. I just want it to jump to a new co-ordinates.

Comment: if you want to that that even simple jump, you need to do that with Animated , because you need to change the frame for showing that move more than once, so even small changes need to be done withing `Animated`

Comment: check the Examples at https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#animated-api

Comment: i updated my answer, another solution came to my mind

Answer (score 0):

try to make the positionX and poitionY as **state**
to re render again when they change

```
const [positionX,setPositionX]=useState(20)
// same for y
```

and in the function

```
setPositionX(100)
```

Comment: How do I call `setPositionX(100)` from a different scope? I came to the same conclusion as you but I can't edit this from another function.

Comment: If the button in the same compnent of the text 
```
 <Button onPress={()=>setPositionX(100)}
```

Comment: so steps 
1- declare the states in the component
2- use thesse states in the Text
3- change it by the button